# Untagging activities

Tags: activities, tags

I have a search result of activities tagged with a certain activity-tag.

How do I untag them, without updating each single activity?

CiviCRM version 4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to a 4.4 system, but I think the solution is the same as in 4.6. You would select the tagged activities in your search, and then choose an action of 'Untag activities (remove tags)'  This action will untag all the selected activities in one go.

Comment: It seems as this is an improvement from 4.4 to later versions. I found it like that on 4.7